# Understanding Flask request object

Tags: python, flask

I would like to understand how the `request` object from `Flask` works. Specifically, by looking at the code below, taken from [here](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/01/07/flask-parsing-json-data/). 
[image]

My question is: where is the link between the `request`object, and the actual request that is made?

Put another way, how does `request.is_json` knows which data it should point to (the data sent through the request).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are interested in how the `request` object is created, feel free to read the source code. Is there any specific issue related to your question that you are having that we could help you with?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PaxVobiscum. I am new to Flask and I am just trying to understand how does the request object know where to look for the data. Or, maybe this way is clearer, at which line of the code a request object containing the information from the client's request appears/becomes available? Maybe the only explanation is in the source code, I don't know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question or why you would want to know this. Do you want a line number?

Comment: In line 8 there is a request object, and this object points to the actual data that has been requested, right? Where/when is this connection made, that is my question. Is it something inherent to the request object upon its creation? So when this object is imported from Flask it already knows that if there is a request, this object should point to the data provided in the request (POST request)? I hope you understand me better now. It might be a bit of an unnecessary worry, I agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question with the specifics given in the comments, if I understood it correctly;

The `request` object is created when you first start your `Flask` server, however, flask keeps track of a request context stack, there all requests ends up.

[Request stack accessing, source](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/globals.py#L34)

```
def _lookup_req_object(name):
    top = _request_ctx_stack.top
    if top is None:
        raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
    return getattr(top, name)
```

Then the flask calls the specific endpoint for your url and from that endpoint you can access the request object. Since flask actually uses the `BaseRequest` object from werkzeug it inherits the `get_data` method which deserializes the request data for later parsing.

[werkzeug get_data() impllementation, source](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L973)

```
def get_data(self, as_text=False):
    """The string representation of the request body.  Whenever you call
    this property the request iterable is encoded and flattened.  This
    can lead to unwanted behavior if you stream big data.
    This behavior can be disabled by setting
    :attr:`implicit_sequence_conversion` to `False`.
    If `as_text` is set to `True` the return value will be a decoded
    unicode string.
    .. versionadded:: 0.9
    """
    self._ensure_sequence()
    rv = b''.join(self.iter_encoded())
    if as_text:
        rv = rv.decode(self.charset)
    return rv
```

The specific request object again uses inherited mixins to be able to tell json from other content.

```
class Request(RequestBase, JSONMixin):
    """The request object used by default in Flask.  Remembers the
    matched endpoint and view arguments.
    It is what ends up as :class:`~flask.request`.  If you want to replace
    the request object used you can subclass this and set
    :attr:`~flask.Flask.request_class` to your subclass.
    The request object is a :class:`~werkzeug.wrappers.Request` subclass and
    provides all of the attributes Werkzeug defines plus a few Flask
    specific ones.
```

Feel free to continue reading the source if you wanna know more than after my quick time research, or if you have any question just leave a comment.